# how to create an iam role with policy that grants access to the SQS created

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I created 2 SQS and the DeadLetterQueue with the code in my main.tf calling the SQS/main.tf module.I would like to destroy and create them again but this time,I want to call IAM/iam_role.tf as well to create one IAM role together with the policy documents.I don't know how to specify that in my main.tf so that the resources section  of the data policy document has both CloudTrail_SQS created ,meaning "CloudTrail_SQS_Data_Event" and "cloudTrail_SQS_Management_Event" and the resources arn of the S3 give the role access to the 2 different buckets used for the SQS,meaning "cloudtrail-management-event-logs" and "aws-cloudtrail143-sqs-logs"

```
SQS/main.tf
```

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "CloudTrail_SQS"{
    name                       = var.sqs_queue_name
    redrive_policy = jsonencode({
        deadLetterTargetArn    = aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ.arn
        maxReceiveCount        = 4
    })
}
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ"{
    name                       = var.dead_queue_name
```

```
IAM/iam_role.tf
```

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "access_role" {
  name               = var.role_name
  description        = var.description
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.trust_relationship.json
}
```

```
trust policy
```

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "trust_relationship" {
  statement {
    sid     = "AllowAssumeRole"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [var.account_id]
    }

    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "sts:ExternalId"

      values = [var.external_id]
    }
  }
}
```

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy_document"{
  statement{
    actions = [
      "sqs:GetQueueUrl",
      "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
      "sqs:SendMessage"
    ]
    effect = "Allow"
    resources = aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS.arn
  }
  statement {
    actions = ["sqs:ListQueues"]
    effect  = "Allow"
    resources = ["*"]
  }
  statement {
    actions = ["s3:GetObject", "s3:GetBucketLocation"]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.cloudtrail_event_log_bucket_name}/*"
    ]
    effect = "Allow"
  }
  statement {
    actions = ["s3:ListBucket"]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::${var.cloudtrail_event_log_bucket_name}"
    ]
    effect = "Allow"
  }
  statement {
    actions = ["kms:Decrypt", "kms:GenerateDataKey","kms:DescribeKey" ]
    effect = "Allow"
    resources = [var.kms_key_arn]
  }
}
```

```
main.tf
```

```
module "data_events"{
  source = "../SQS"

  cloudtrail_event_log_bucket_name = "aws-cloudtrail143-sqs-logs"
  sqs_queue_name                   = "CloudTrail_SQS_Data_Event"
  dead_queue_name                  = "CloudTrail_DLQ_Data_Event"
}


module "management_events"{
  source = "../SQS"

  cloudtrail_event_log_bucket_name = "cloudtrail-management-event-logs"
  sqs_queue_name                   = "cloudTrail_SQS_Management_Event"
  dead_queue_name                  = "cloudTrail_DLQ_Management_Event"

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current policy? Any errors?

Comment: its creating a duplicate role but i only want to create one role then grant the role access to the 2 s3 bucket created abd also grant the role access to the 2 created SQS

Comment: Why would it create a duplicate role? Your code does not show any such scenario. In fact you are not using `IAM/iam_role.tf` at all.

Comment: im not sure what im doing wrong.i would like to be able to call the IAM and SQS at thesame time and have it create just one role and grant the role access to the 2 SQS and 2 S3 bucket access

Comment: i dont know how to reference that line of code in my main.tf

Comment: I provided the answer, but your code has so many mistakes and lots of missing information (e.g. no full definition of the modules given), that its not viable to provide working code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [data](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/data-sources/index.html) sources of terraform.

At this time, you should write the output for SQS folder, write them as data in IAM folder and use it

Answer (score 2):

The role would be created as shown below. But your question has so many mistakes and missing information, that its impossible to provide full, working code. So the below code should be treated as a template which you need to adjust for your use.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "access_role" {
  name               = var.role_name
  description        = var.description
  
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          Service = "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
    ]
  })
  
  inline_policy {
    name   = "allow-access-to-s3-sqs"
    policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.policy_document.json
  }  
  
}


data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy_document"{
  statement{
    actions = [
      "sqs:GetQueueUrl",
      "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
      "sqs:SendMessage"
    ]
    effect = "Allow"
    resources = [
           module.data_events.sqs.arn,
           module.management_events.sqs.arn,
           ]
  }
  statement {
    actions = ["sqs:ListQueues"]
    effect  = "Allow"
    resources = ["*"]
  }
  statement {
    actions = ["s3:GetObject", "s3:GetBucketLocation"]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::aws-cloudtrail143-sqs-logs/*"
      "arn:aws:s3:::cloudtrail-management-event-logs/*"
    ]
    effect = "Allow"
  }
  statement {
    actions = ["s3:ListBucket"]
    resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::aws-cloudtrail143-sqs-logs",
      "arn:aws:s3:::cloudtrail-management-event-logs"      
    ]
    effect = "Allow"
  }
  statement {
    actions = ["kms:Decrypt", "kms:GenerateDataKey","kms:DescribeKey" ]
    effect = "Allow"
    resources = [var.kms_key_arn]
  }
}
```

Comment: ,thank you for the template,its exactly what I need.Do i need to add anything to my Main.tf where I am calling SQS and IAM configuration

Comment: @bibi As I wrote, what code you provided is incorrect anyway. There are many issues. One example, missing quotation marks, role has no trust policy, modules are undefined, ... So with or without the role, your code will not work.

Comment: i will update the code

Comment: code as been updated

Comment: @bibi I would suggest taking my answer, trying to write your own code or IAM module based on it. A lot will depend on exactly how `data_events` and `management_events` modules are defined, especially what do they return. This is not shown in the current question, and would be good place to start in new one. Also you must indicate how would you like to use your IAM module after you create `data_events` and `management_events` modules ? How do you pass input variables to IAM module?

Comment: thank you @marcin